# Setting Values of enum via Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I have a system where I have an enum of Shops for example. These shows each have their own ShopCommand property (some of which share the same type of command class). from a method in the command class I then want to call send on a Spring Integration gateway. Where I'm confused is how to actually insantiate this gateway in spring. Ideally what I want is to construct the enum via XML configuration with command property being created also in spring, which has the property outGateway set via Spring. I'm not sure if I've made myself very clear with this descrition, if clarification is needed then just ask!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking for:

Say I have an enum for ShopType

```
public enum ShopType {
  GROCERY, DEPARTMENT, MALL; 
}
```

Then I have some Store bean that I want to setup via spring configuration.  You can instantiate and use the enum like this:

```
<bean id="DEPTARTMENT_STORE" class="my.package.ShopType" factory-method="valueOf">
  <constructor-arg value="DEPARTMENT"/>
</bean>

<bean id="searsStore" class="my.package.Store">
  <property name="shopType" ref="DEPTARTMENT_STORE"/>
</bean>
```

The factory-method points to a static method that is used to create the object.  So you can use the enum's method "valueOf" as a factory method.